# Override preview view file in Impresspages

Tags: php, impresspages

I would like to override the default "Preview Mode" view template but i cant find any template file which seems to generate this view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ip/Internal/Admin/view/navbar.php  is probably the right file. It iterates $navbarButtons array.

If you just want to add / remove something from there, use filter ipAdminNavbarButtons

Comment: thanks, but what i was looking for is the not exactly the navbar itself. The preview mode loads the admin.css file from the ip core.

Comment: [..] "Ip/Internal/Core/assets/admin/admin.css" in the header. I'd like to add my own stylesheet from my theme to load after the core admin.css to take affect.

Comment: So add those CSS files after `ipHead();` and you should be good to go.

Comment: if you will use ipAddCss instead of plane HTML structure, then do it before ipHead() :)